# Putty connection refused until server login

Tags: linux, redhat, putty

Our Red hat main host reboots every night and when I try to connect with Putty I get connection refused. Then after I physically go to the server and login to it and go back to my other computer I am able to connect to it with Putty.  This worked for us without logging into the server until we changed the DNS ip address. But then changed dns ip address back and putty still can't connect until after logging in.

Comment: Is there a cron job at login for the said user to bring the ssh daemon up? should probably check that.

Comment: No there isn't a cron job for ssh. I never had one before and I was able to connect. None of the VMs on the server have a cron job and I can connect to any of those with putty without logging into them.

Comment: Check the network config. Seems you not have network until you login

Comment: Thanks! I went into System > Preferences > Network connections.
Opened the network connection and Checked the box "Available to all users". After reboot, I was able to connect with Putty.